# Adjusting a SELECT statement containing a LEFT OUTER JOIN to an UPDATE statement from the same table- is it possible?

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

As a newby, I've hunted high, and low to find a solution to my problem. Hoping someone can shed some light on a solution.

I have a SELECT statement that spits out Reports as desired. What I'd like to do is have an UPDATE statement that updates my table column named report with the resulting number. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
SELECT
    l.id,
    l.plate,
    COUNT(*) AS Reports
FROM
    coh_items AS l
LEFT OUTER JOIN coh_items AS r
ON
    l.id >= r.id AND l.plate = r.plate
GROUP BY
    l.id,
    l.plate
;
```

Comment: Please provide a relevant and minimal sample data showcasing your requirements, and expected output. Refer this link on how to frame a good SQL question: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/2469308)

Comment: Also , note that it's generally considered bad practice to store easily derived data

Comment: To answer your question: Yes, it's possible.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response. 
Madhur - it looks like SQL Fiddle may be having some technical difficulties.
Strawberry - Thank you for your observation.
Steffen - Danke. Perhaps I ought to have asked  - How? :-)

Comment: The sqlfiddle was optional. The DDLs were not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
update coh_items i left join
       (select i.id, i.plate, count(*) as reports
        from coh_items i left join
             coh_items i2
             on i.id >= i2.id and i.plate = i2.plate
        group by i.id, i.place
       ) i2
       using (id, plate)
    set i.reports = i2.reports;
```

The left join seems unnecessary because any given row is always going to match itself (assuming the comparison columns are not `NULL`).

Comment: Gordon, you're a star. THANK YOU!